# App logo is not shown after firebase app indexing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, cordova-plugin-fcm, google-indexing-api

Please have a look at my manifest file

the app is shwoing its default icons everywhere (in app listing , FCM notifications etc) even i replaced the files(ic_launcher.png) with my logo icons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Welcome_Screen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="www.mywebsite.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Latest_Webview" />

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />

</application>
```

and the gradle file dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'}
```

Comment: Try to remove `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` check will result be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear about the question but what I am assuming is that you named your icon as ic_launcher.png and replaced the default one . The problem here is that it is still getting the old icon reference. The solution to this problem is go to your project location app->src->main->res->mipmap-anydpi-v26(latest version) and delete these two xml files i.e ic_launcher and ic_launcher round.
There is no harm in deleting these as they will be automatically created again in accordance with the new icons.